# JAVA HIbernate 4.2.4: Add additional hibernate criteria (AND condition) to 3 joined entities without using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-onetomany

I am trying to join 3 entities using hibernate criteria with relation defined as follows:

- Each Employee has one Department and a Specialization.
- A Department could have many Employees.
- A Department may contain more than one Specializations.
- One Specialization could belong to many Departments.

I want to get a response given an Employee's ID with all its details. The problem here is that Employee and Specialization  entities do not have a direct foreign key relationship between them. And hence I am not able to join the two entities.

Below some sample data:

Employee:

```
| emp_id | emp_name | emp_specialization | dept_id |
|:-------|---------:|:------------------:|--------:|
| 1      |     John |         electronics|        1|
| 2      |     Wick |               frame|        2|
| 3      |    Three |               radar|        1|
```

Department:

```
| dept_id | dept_name |
|:-------|-----------:|
| 1      | F21 Raptor |
| 2      | F35 Panther|
```

Specialization:

```
| spec_id | dept_id | spec_name          | 
|:-------|---------:|:------------------:|
| 1      |         1|         electronics|
| 2      |         1|               frame|
| 3      |         2|               radar|
```

As given, emp_specialization and spec_name define a relationship between the two entities - Employee and Specialization.

Here are the snippets for 3 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
Class Employee {
private Long emp_id;
private String emp_name;
private String emp_specialization;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
private Department department;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
Class Department {
private Long deptId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="dept_id", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Specialization> specialization;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Specialization")
Class Specialization {
private Long spec_id;
private Long dept_id;
private String spec_name;
}
```

```java
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("emp_id", 1));
List<Employee> empList = criteria.list();
```

The above criteria results in below SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    Employee.* 
FROM 
    Employee emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Department dpt
        ON emp.dept_id = dpt.dept_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Specialization spec
        ON dpt.dept_id =  spec.dept_id
WHERE emp.emp_id = 1
```

But this results in multiple Specializations for Employee with ID=1 :

```
{
    "Employee": [{
            "emp_id": 1,
            "emp_name": "John",
            "emp_spec": "electronics",
            "department": {
                "dept_id": 1,
                "dept_name": "F21 Raptor",
                "specialization": [{
                        "spec_id": 1,
                        "spec_name" "electronics"
                    }, {
                        "spec_id": 2,
                        "spec_name" "frame"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I really want is something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    Employee.* 
FROM 
    Employee emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Department dpt
        ON emp.dept_id = dpt.dept_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Specialization spec
        ON dpt.dept_id =  spec.dept_id
WHERE emp.emp_id = 1
AND emp.emp_specialization = spec.spec_name
```

And would give a response in below JSON format:

```
{
    "Employee": [{
            "emp_id": 1,
            "emp_name": "John",
            "emp_spec": "electronics",
            "department": {
                "dept_id": 1,
                "dept_name": "F21 Raptor",
                "specialization": {
                    "spec_id": 1,
                    "spec_name" "electronics"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA), return the Employee and serialize it to JSON.